# Displaying php array in three column, first row one element and second and third row two element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
$b = 0;
foreach ($settings['items'] as $item){
    $b++;
    if ($b==1){
        $out .='First';
    } else{
        $out2 .='Second';
    }
 }

 echo '<div class="inner">'.$out.'</div>';
 echo '<div class="inner">'.$out2.'</div>';
```

which output

```
 <div class="inner">First</div>
 <div class="inner">Second Second Second Second</div>
```

But I would like to have this structure

```
 <div class="inner">First</div>
 <div class="inner">Second Second</div>
 <div class="inner">Second Second</div>
```

One probable solution that I thought is using `array_slice` But for first loop I only need one element not two, that's why I think I can not do that.

Comment: Where is `$out2` come from?

Comment: Use the modulo operator on the loop counter. `$b % 3 == 0` means first column, `$b % 3 != 0` means second or third. (Requires starting your counter at 0 for the first item.)

Comment: Or split your array into chunks of size 3.

Comment: You can also get the first element, unset it, and slice the array into chunks of size 2. easy

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$first = true;
$all = [];
$couples = [];
foreach ($settings['items'] as $item){
    if($first){
        $first = false;
        $first_out = 'First'; //or whatever
        $all[] = $first_out;
    }else{
        if(count($couples) == 2){
            $all[] = $couples;
            $couples = [];
        }
        $couples[] = 'Second';
    }
}
foreach($all as $value){
    echo '<div class="inner">'.implode(',', $value).'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little pre-wrangling, remove the first item, and then merge it into the remaining chunked array.

```
<?php
$items   = array_fill(0, 5, 'foo'); // An array of five 'foo's.
$first   = array_shift($items);
$chunked = array_chunk($items, 2);
$chunked = array_merge([[$first]], $chunked);

var_dump($chunked);

foreach($chunked as $chunk)
{
    echo '<div class="inner">' . implode(' ', $chunk) . "</div>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    }
}
<div class="inner">foo</div>
<div class="inner">foo foo</div>
<div class="inner">foo foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't use value of $settings['items'] in the code, you can just work with that array length

```
$count = count($settings['items']);
if ($count--) echo `<div class="inner">First</div>`;
while($count > 1) {
   echo '<div class="inner">Second Second</div>';
   $count -= 2;
}
if ($count--) echo `<div class="inner">Second</div>`;
```

Comment: I will use $settings['items']

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out,

```
$b = 0;
for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++){
    $b++;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $b;$i++){
        switch($b){
            case '1': echo '<div class="inner">FIRST</div>';break;
            case '2': echo '<div class="inner">SECOND SECOND</div>';break;
        }
    }
}
```